# Customize Gems or merge into main rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am writing a Ruby on Rails application, and I am using Gems, however sometimes I feel that Gems are not as flexible as I want them to be. To make them more flexible. Should I

**Fork them on github, and customize it, but this still present the challenging of managing everything.**

or

**Strip and merge the code of the gem to the main application? This will allow further customization of the gem. This would be for situations where a Gem require another Gem's functionality.**

or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks
B

Comment: Both options will give you the same amount of flexibility for the code, since in both cases you'd be managing the code. However, forking will allow you to merge the changes on the original gem's repository if you so wish.

Comment: The idea is so that I can use Gem X's functionality in Gem Y. Such adding "make_votable" in the model of Gem Y

Comment: Then build the gem Y dependent on gem X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choice A is the better answer for a number of reasons.

1. You get to merge in security updates, enhancements, and bug fixes easily.
2. Your changes may get merged into the core--in fact, consider if you could implement them in such a way as they live alongside the core functionality as options. If this happens, you have the ultimate win--nothing to maintain, and you can retire your fork.
3. Others can benefit from your changes.
4. Your project's footprint is kept smaller and focused by keeping the gem code isolated.
5. You'll have something to add to your Github "resume."

Comment: Thanks for the benefits, I think the solution will be a) and "Then build the gem Y dependent on gem X".

Answer (score 0):

If its some kind if not so popular gem or "bicycle" from some previous studio or developer who started project(in my case).
I prefer deprecate this gem's and move code into project,
for example they have c***la-deploy - it's just wrapper to Capistrano 2 with own methods))) - I just delete it and rewrite on last Capistrano 3
Than that have own "CMS" c***la-cms where they wrap standard form_for or simple_form with name "twitter_form_for" ? - fist of all I start try to find gem who use this name, and than find in dependency gem's ...
Its take a lot of time for new developer involve in project - better move to standard rails methods/heplers
But anyway i understand for a what this studio do that - its just vendor lock and for client more hard to move out from them to another developers.
For example for startup its bad to use a lot of dependencies and if it's just simple website - dose not matter.

Comment: My choice in most of case B